# How to prevent typing whitespace in TextEdit QML?

Tags: qt, qml

How to prevent typing whitespace in TextEdit? QML

```
TextEdit {
    width: 240
    text: "123"
    font.pointSize: 20
    color: "blue"
}
```

Comment: xszi, can you clarify your question? There is probably more than one way to solve this; so it would depend...exactly how would you use it? A Minimal, Reproducible Example [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can change text input item from TextEdit to TextInput can use validator and regular expressions

from doc :

> The RegExpValidator type provides a validator, which counts as valid any string which matches a specified regular expression.

in another way can get the onTextChanged signal and remove whitespace :
like this :

```
TextEdit {
    width: 240
    text: "123"
    font.pointSize: 20
    color: "blue"
    onTextChanged:text = text.replace(/\s+/g,'')
}
```